# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
newcentences = []
for i in range(len(comments)):
    comment = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]',' ',comments["Review"][i]).lower().split()
    comment = [ps.stem(word) for word in comment if not word in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
    comment = ' '.join(comment)
    newcentences.append(comment)


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 1000)

X = cv.fit_transform(newcentences).toarray()
y = comments.iloc[:,-1].values 


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.33)


from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

gnb = GaussianNB()
gnb.fit(x_train,y_train)

y_pred = gnb.predict(x_test)
```

I'm trying to make an example of natural language processing. I have a dataset called comments. After running the code, the second to last line gives an error. Can someone help?

Comment: What are some typical `y = comments.iloc[:,-1].values`?  ... max? ... min?

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset contains bad values -

You can check by -

1. `np.isnan(X)` you get a boolean mask back with True for positions containing `NaNs`.
2. `np.where(np.isnan(X))` you get back a tuple with i, j coordinates of `NaNs`.
3. `np.nan_to_num(X)` you "replace nan with zero and inf with finite numbers".

For imputation -

1. [sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html) for mean / median imputation of missing values,

or

2. pandas `pd.DataFrame(X).fillna()`, if you need something other than filling it with zeros.